# select2 gives duplicate dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I'm working on a B2B ordering app and was using simple select/dropdowns to provide products to order and adding additional lines with jquery as needed - all working perfectly.  I've now changed the select to select2 to provide searching.  The first item works correctly, but if you add an additional line, it provides the select2 box plus a copy of the first line that's read-only.  see image below..

[image]

code relevant to the select2 dropdown

```
@foreach (old('products', ['']) as $index => $oldProduct)
  <tr id="product{{ $index }}">
    <td>
      <select name="StockItem[]" class="select2 form-control mb-3 custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;" >
        <option value="">-- choose product --</option>
          @foreach ($products as $product)
            <option value="{{ $product->id }}"{{ $oldProduct == $product->id ? ' selected' : '' }}>
              {{ $product->StockItemName }} -
                (R {{ !floatval($product->DiscountPercentage) ?
                ( !empty($product->UnitPrice) ? number_format($product->UnitPrice, 2) : number_format($product->SellingPrice, 2) )
                : number_format($product->SellingPrice - (($product->DiscountPercentage / 100) * $product->SellingPrice), 2) }})
            </option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let row_number = {{ count(old('products', [''])) }};
    $("#add_row").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      let new_row_number = row_number - 1;
      $('#product' + row_number).html($('#product' + new_row_number).html()).find('td:first-child');
      $('#products_table').append('<tr id="product' + (row_number + 1) + '"></tr>');
      row_number++;
      $('select').select2();
    });
});
```

I'm assuming my problem is with the reload of select2 `$('select').select2();`

if you save this form, the correct data gets saved without any unnecessary duplicates.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why yo use select tag inside loop?

Comment: Perhaps it printed because of loop iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this behaviour because `select2` plugin creates its own html so when you use `.html()` to get content from `tr` you are getting that dynamically generated html as well . Instead you can use `.clone()` to clone your `tr` and then from this cloned tr get *options* from select-box and append all inside your newly generated tr .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".custom-select").select2();
  let row_number = 1; //just for demo..
  $("#add_row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = $("#products_table tbody tr:first").find("[name='StockItem[]']").html(); //get option inside select..
    var cloned = $("#products_table tbody tr:first").clone() //get whole tr..

    $(cloned).find("td:first").html('<select name="StockItem[]" class="select2 form-control mb-3 custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">' + options + '</select>') //add option ..
    $(cloned).find("input").val("") //empty input values ..

    $('#products_table tbody').append('<tr id="product' + (row_number + 1) + '">' + $(cloned).html() + '</tr>'); //append whole content
    $('tbody tr:last select').select2(); //intialize your select2
    row_number++;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<table id="products_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="product0">
      <td>
        <select name="StockItem[]" class="select2 form-control mb-3 custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">
          <option value="">-- choose product --</option>
          <option value="{{ $product->id }}">
            abc
          </option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="product1">
      <td>
        <select name="StockItem[]" class="select2 form-control mb-3 custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">
          <option value="">-- choose product --</option>
          <option value="{{ $product->id }}">
            abc
          </option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="add_row">Add</button>
```

Comment: thanks, that definitely helped a lot and fixed the duplicate line issue... for some reason, I get a normal select and not a select2 dropdown (like in your code snippet), but at least the duplicate line is sorted.

Comment: Then, instead of `$('tbody tr:last select').select2();` try : `$('#products_table .custom-select:last').select2()` or `$("select").select2()`

Comment: perfect! ```$("select").select2()``` has done it.